# Is it possible to create a phone answering machine program on android phones?

Tags: android, telephony

I am researching for my next android app project. ( My wife and I created the Mayan Calendar Countdown 2012 App ) I want to create a phone answering machine for android phones that have all the capabilities of a normal home phone answering machine. The recording of a message to answer with seems relatively easy but I am unsure how to play that message back to the incoming caller.

Is this app possible without some hack that will make it unacceptable for android market?
I have a lot of c++ experience and have setup the ndk etc.

BTW stackoverflow is great. I am very impressed with the knowledge here.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devindia.acr&hl=en

Comment: HI Stytrim Did you get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no way in the standard Java API to programmatically answer an incoming call.  This appears to be one of the features that is reserved by the OS.

Comment: I suspected as much. The telephony api is very limited. Thanks for the reply